# Python async unitest - assert False doesn't fail the test

Tags: python, unit-testing

I'm trying to check api that I wrote with FastAPI. As part of it I started a Postgres container and I wrote a test that connects to the db. I wanted to check if the api works:

```
class ServiceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # All tests requires that there will be up a db container up
    # docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=123 -e POSTGRES_USER=user -e POSTGRES_DB=dev -p 5432:5432 --name postgres12_container postgres:12.1-alpine

    async def test_get_index_page(self):
        logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)
        log = logging.getLogger("TestLog")
        log.debug("debug message")
        await startup()
        client = TestClient(app)
        response = client.get("/api/v1/my-ms/")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        assert False, "assert failed"
```

Now as you can see, the last line should fail the test but it doesn't happen - the assert doesn't work. The test is passing successfully. When I delete the "async" of the function definition the test fails. However, I need the async because the startup func is async.

I'm using Python 3.7.4.

Comment: Have you tried with https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase

Comment: This class isnt available on python 3.7.4

Comment: Then I think you'd have to use e.g. https://pypi.org/project/aiounittest/

Comment: Well, I guess it solved the original issue but i'm still getting an error related to async - E           RuntimeError: This event loop is already running of  the client.get(..) call. Any idea what can explain this ?

Comment: try to check IsolatedAsyncioTestCase from unittest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to use aiounittest as jonrsharpe recommended in the comments but I got another error related to the event loop. Therefore I decided to work with the `asyncio` dir and get the event loop by myself:

```
import unittest
import asyncio
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from app.main import app
from app.main import startup

client = TestClient(app)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(startup()) # connect to the db


class ServiceTest(unittest.TestCase):
    # All tests requires that there will be up a db container up
    # docker run -d -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=history_db_password -e POSTGRES_USER=history_db_username -e POSTGRES_DB=history_db_dev -p 5432:5432 --name postgres12_container postgres:12.1-alpine

    def test_get_index_page(self):
        response = client.get("/api/v1/history_manager/")
        assert response.status_code == 200
        print(response)
```

I also tried to use `asyncio.run(startup())` but then I got an exception in the `client.get()` that an operation is already in progress. So, I guess I'll stay with this way of testing in the mean time.